# Iterate Through Recordset in Access 2010 VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have to iterate through a table and test 14 different fields for a certain value. All of these fields have a similar name, e.g. `foo 1`, `foo 2`, `foo 3` etc.

I want to use a For loop to iterate through the different fields so I can condense 15 `If-Else If` statements to something like the following

```
For i = 2 to 15
    Dim fieldname as String
    fieldname = "foo " + i
    If conditionMet(MyTableRecordSet![fieldname]) Then
         'Update another column
    End If
Next i
```

But I know if I do it this way VBA will look for a field literally named "fieldname", it won't interpolate the variable's value as I wish. Is there a way to get the variable's value in there? If not, is there another way to systematically go through a record's values without too many `If-Else If` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
For i = 2 To 15
    Dim fieldname As String
    fieldname = "foo " & i
    If conditionMet(MyTableRecordSet(fieldname)) Then
         'Update another column
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I rarely program in VBA so I'm unfamiliar with its idiosyncrasies.